# Adding a scroll view behind view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

Hey, I've been trying to add a scroll view to my view for sometime now and I can't seem to get it work. I've been trying some tutorials without luck. Could anyone aid me in this? It is just basically a normal view with some buttons on it.

Thanks.

Comment: What specifically have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: I have tried setting the scrollview behind the view and setting the content size thing bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common mistake I've seen with UIScrollView usage is forgetting to set contentSize. contentSize needs to be bigger than the size of the UIScrollView for scrolling to make sense.